# Rigging a character and adding controlls issue

Tags: animation, rigging

So I was rigging my low poly char and when I was doing the kinetic inverse thingy for my arm it just spun the entire arm and spine around and I don't know what I did wrong https://gyazo.com/0814389d1cb7da5a3d5045bd30f3d79d?token=a409b6a09f7abc895a9abfebeade9209

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you gotta change the pole angle yo 90 or -90, is a thing of inverse kinematics in blender. Let me know if that helps !